# Change DoubleAnimation From property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have defined Storyboard with DoubleAnimation in it and I need to change From value in code-behind before starting the animation. How can I do it?

This doesn't work - I get an exception *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SB_showhide" Duration="0:0:1">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="move" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Left)" From="0" To="500" />
</Storyboard>

((DoubleAnimation)FindName("move")).From = 200;
BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)FindResource("SB_showhide"));
```

Comment: `move` is nothing - I have no variable like that.

Comment: Is it feasible to move the entire Storyboard to codebehind? See Terry's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900627/creating-storyboard-in-code-behind-in-wpf .

Comment: Yes, it is. I just wanted to know, where is the problem.

Comment: I have it in my `Wnd : Window` which is created in my `MainEnvironment` class, which is created in `OnStartup` method in App.xaml.cs. The files my code is written in are named `Wnd.xaml` and `Wnd.xaml.cs`.

Comment: `MainEnvironment` is a class which should initialize and start the application. It is not a window, just a class. And here I have `Wnd mainWnd = new Wnd();`. I don't think this is important.

Comment: I did. It shows me an error: _The name 'move' does not exist in the current context_.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
var storyboard = (Storyboard)Resources["SB_showhide"];
var move = (DoubleAnimation)storyboard.Children[0];
move.From = 200;
```