# How to assign the height property of the parent container to the to parameter of DoubleAnimation in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

As the title says, I want to know how to assign the height(or `ActualHeight`) of the container to the `To` parameter/attribute of `DoubleAnimation` in xaml?

Here is my code:

```
<Canvas Name="animCanvas">
    <Rectangle 
        Name="animSquare"
        Canvas.Left="0"
        Fill="AliceBlue"
        Stroke="Bisque"
        StrokeThickness="5"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        >
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="animSquare"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                            From="0"
                            To="500" <!-- I want to set it to the containers height -->
                            Duration="0:0:1"
                        />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps use code-behind to create the storyboard? To get you started: [Creating Storyboard in code behind in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900627/creating-storyboard-in-code-behind-in-wpf). In code behind, you can definitely find out the parent's height and pass it to the `To` parameter.

Comment: I prefer to use plain xaml as long as possible. Isn't it possible using plain xaml?

Comment: Actually the answer below has got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply Binding to the `To` property of double animation like this :

```
To="{Binding ElementName=animSquare, Path=Height}"
```

I think this would solve your issue.